# merge array using angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two array:

var obj1 = [{ "a" : "1", "b" : "2" }, { "a" : "3", "b" : "4" }];

var obj2 = [{ "c" : "5", "d" : "6" }, { "c" : "7", "d" : "8" }];

I want final output as:

objFinal: [{ "a" : "1", "b" : "2", "c" : "5", "d" : "6" }, { "a" : "3", "b" : "4", "c" : "7", "d" : "8" }];

I am working on angular 5 with TS

Comment: Please don't change the question once you get answers. It's not fair to the people who went to the trouble of answering your previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the spread operator (ES2015)

```
let objFinal = [{...obj1[0], ...obj2[0]}, {...obj1[1], ...obj2[1]}];
```

should work,

Comment: I would just like to add this is supported from ES2015

Comment: there is slight change in question. Can you please guide me in this

Comment: changed my answer

Comment: @ĽubošČurgó [Rest / spread operators in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) are part of the [ES2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#9th_Edition_-_ECMAScript_2018) feature spec.

Comment: You're right sorry, the question is about TypeScript and it works. 
I also tried with StackBlitz and pure JavaScript and it works. I don;t know which version of ES are they using (in the template description they say ES6)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use the JavaScript Array.concat function.

objFinal = obj1.concat(obj2)

Should do the trick.

Comment: there is slight change in question. Can you please guide me in this

Answer (score 0):

let objFinal=[... obj1,... obj2]

It's plain Javascript.

Comment: there is slight change in question. Can you please guide me in this